# MS get call record graph api

Tags: call, microsoft-teams, subscription, microsoft-graph-api

Get call record api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http has rate limit of 5000 requests per 10 seconds. It is per app for all tenants.

I wanted to understand "per app for all tenants". Suppose there are 2 apps for same tenant then each app has limit of 5000 req per 10 seconds ?

Comment: As mentioned by you "per app for all tenants", so each app will have their own App registration, App service etc.
So for 2 apps, there will be different resources and for each app will have their own rate limit of 5000 requests per 10 seconds.

Comment: ohh, as app can be multi tenant, here "for all tenant" implies limit for app in case of multiple tenants using same app. Thanks @ChetanSharma-msft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding answer from comment section for more visibilty.

For "per app for all tenants", so each app will have their own App registration, App service etc. So for 2 apps, there will be different resources and for each app will have their own rate limit of 5000 requests per 10 seconds.